# Merging 3 querys in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I wondered if there was a way you could merge these 3 querys in Laravel while still checking the Auth::check() ?

```
public function getBannedView(Request $request)
{
    $banCount = GameBan::where('ban_type', 'ip_ban')->where('ban_value', $request->ip())->whereRaw('expires_at > now()')->count();
    $banCountUsername = Auth::check() ? GameBan::where('ban_type', 'user_ban')->where('ban_value', Auth::user()->username)->whereRaw('expires_at > now()')->count() : 0;
    $banCountMachine = Auth::check() ? GameBan::where('ban_type', 'machine_ban')->where('ban_username', Auth::user()->username)->whereRaw('expires_at > now()')->count() : 0;

    if ($banCount < 1) {
        return redirect()->route("login");
    }

    return view('other.banned');
}
```

Comment: So for all queries you have to be loggged in (so basically for the whole function)?

Comment: The first one just requires the IP, so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$banCount = GameBan::where('ban_type', 'ip_ban')->where('ban_value', $request->ip())->whereRaw('expires_at > now()')
    ->when(Auth::check(), function ($query) {
        $query->orWhere('ban_type', 'user_ban')->where('ban_value', Auth::user()->username)->whereRaw('expires_at > now()');
        $query->orWhere('ban_type', 'machine_ban')->where('ban_username', Auth::user()->username)->whereRaw('expires_at > now()');
    })->count();
```

Comment: Thank you, this option is much shorter and actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do it in single DB query,

```
$banCountQuery = GameBan::where(function ($query) use($request) {
    $query->where('ban_type', 'ip_ban');
    $query->orWhere('ban_value', $request->ip());
});

if (Auth::check()) {
    $banCountQuery->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('ban_type', 'user_ban');
        $query->orWhere('ban_value', Auth::user()->username);
    })->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('ban_type', 'machine_ban');
        $query->orWhere('ban_value', Auth::user()->username);
    });
}
$banCount = $banCountQuery->whereRaw('expires_at > now()')->count();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. You need to add `->whereRaw('expires_at > now()')` to each where clause, there is also an issue and you need to update the "orWhere" and "where" as they are wrong.

Comment: Fixed version of yours: $banCountQuery = GameBan::where('ban_type', 'ip_ban')->where('ban_value', $request->ip())->whereRaw('expires_at > now()');
$banCountQuery->orWhere(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('ban_type', 'user_ban');
                $query->where('ban_value', Auth::user()->username)->whereRaw('expires_at > now()');
            })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('ban_type', 'machine_ban');
                $query->where('ban_value', Auth::user()->username)->whereRaw('expires_at > now()');
            });